# Microcontroller bit information for the Core and different peripherals

Tags: microcontroller, register, core

Usually, from what I have seen, Microcontroller have this information of 8-bit, 16-bit and 32-bit.

In this [Microcontroller S32K142](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/S32K-DS.pdf), it is mentioned as 32-bit CPU. So, what does this actually mean?

I understand it like, the Processor core inside the microcontroller has the registers (ALUs) of 32-bit width for the computation. So, a single 32-bit information can be processed at a single time. Or 2x 16-bit information or 4x 8-bit information can be processed at a single time. Am I correct in understanding this?

If so, but the ADC specification is like 12-bit ADC and for timers it is like 16-bit. Why there is a difference like this for different peripherals? Any specific reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your guess is correct, though I doubt many microcontrollers can do arbitrary processing on multiple 16- or 8-bit words at once.

Timers and ADCs are separate hardware from the processor, so they don't have any reason to have the same bit depth as the processor. For ADCs especially, anything higher than 12 or 16 bits gets *extremely* sensitive and either quite expensive or quite slow. You don't generally *need* more ADC resolution than 12 bits, and if you do, you usually will find yourself using a dedicated ADC, not whatever's included on your microcontroller.

As for timers, there's no reason *to* make them the same bit depth as the processor, but also, as far as I'm aware, no reason not to either. I'd have a hard time finding a use for a 32-bit timer, though; I can't imagine needing that much resolution. A 24-bit timer with a prescaler would be more than enough in my book (though 16-bit might be pushing it for resolution).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. When you say, "arbitrary processing on multiple 16- or 8-bit words at once", what does it mean? Unable to understand arbitrary processing?

Comment: By that I mean I doubt it can do just any operation you want on multiple words at once. Processors aren't usually designed to work that way, though some can be.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. But could you tell why it would be difficult to do that?

Comment: @Newbie It's not difficult, just that it would require additional hardware and it's not seen as necessary.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 6):

The ‘bitness’ of a cpu is a disputed topic. My take is the width of the ALU and data path. The fact that the Z80 is believed to be an 8bit cpu but had only a 4 bit ALU contradicts this. Your chip has an ARM Cortex M4 cpu. ARM declares this as a 32bit cpu - who am I to argue? Its alu can do a 32bit add in one clock, but not four 8bit adds or two 16bit adds.—correction— The cm4 has SIMD (single instruction, multiple data)instructions that do this from same source/destination registers.

Consider a 32 bit ADC - what is one four thousand millionth of 3V? A very very small voltage. So small it would be dwarfed by noise. With current technology it would be difficult if not impossible. A 12bit ADC on the other hand is relatively easy.

Timers - 16 bit. How about an 8 bit cpu with 24bit timers? You would need to do three 8 bit reads to get the timer value. Basically there is nothing set in stone that a 8 bit cpu can only have an 8 bit timer or a 32 bit cpu must have a 32bit timer.
For tasks like pwm, 16 bits is usually adequate for most tasks.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So, you're saying that a 32-bit CPU can add two 32-bit numbers in a single clock but cannot add four 8bits and two 16bits? May I know what might be the reason?

Comment: An add operation consists of two operands for one result. My intent was to say is that the ALU won’t do four independent 8 bit adds at once. Technically, you could design an ALU to do this, but it is usually not something the average cpu implements. Why? You’d have to arrange the input from 4 separate sources. How would you read four different registers at once on one bus? The complexity and implementation cost would outweigh tge advantage.

Comment: To be picky, the Cortex M4 does have SIMD instructions, `add8` and `add16` which can do 4 * 8 bit adds or 2 * 16 bit adds in a single cycle. You're right though that you need to wrestle the data into the correct format for these instructions.

Comment: @colin. I stand corrected. I’ve not had cause to use the simd instructions, so you’ve opened my eyes. The trick is the source/destination are the same so the carry/borrow logic is manipulated.

Comment: Bitness isn't so much disputed as vaguely defined. The Z80 had a 4 bit ALU and instructions for 8 and 16 bit data manipulation, but no 4 bit instructions (except arguably DAA, RLD and RRD). It "expects" data to be 8 bit tho, so I'd call it 8 bit.